# How to write a multi-line Python string: triple quotes vs the parenthesis "trick"

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, multiline

So I usually write multi-line strings like this:

```
>>> s = """hello this is the first line
... and this is the second"""
>>> s
'hello this is the first line\nand this is the second'
```

But recently I encountered this:

```
>>> s = ( 'hello this is the first line'
... 'and this is the second' )
>>> s
'hello this is the first lineand this is the second'
```

Ok so `line\nand` became `lineand`. Are there other differences between these two approaches? When should I use the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First things first, the 'parentheses trick' is not actually a multi-line string, just implicit line joining.  This behaviour of python is documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining).

The way you have written they are different things, so which you should use depends if you want a newline in your string or not.

If you are feeling tempted to use the parenthesized version, and explicitly put the `\n` character into each line, a better alternative is to use [`textwrap.dedent`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent).

Answer (score 3):

The second form is essentially an implicit concatenation. You'd use it when you need to write a very long string that's supposed to be on a single line, but you want to make it easier to read in an IDE/text editor (which usually can only display about 80-100 characters on screen per line at a time).

Answer (score -2):

```
>>> s = ( 'hello this is the first line'
... 'and this is the second' )
>>> s = ( 'hello this is the first line''and this is the second' )
>>> s = ( 'hello this is the first lineand this is the second' )
>>> s = 'hello this is the first lineand this is the second'
```

results are

```
>>> s
'hello this is the first lineand this is the second'
```